# Move angularjs app to Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ubuntu-16.04

I have an angular app developed on windows using nodejs, http-server, gulp and brackets. In windows I have a root directory (lms) containing:

```
/src
/src/templates
/src/js
/src/img
/src/index.html
/node_modules
package.json
```

In Ubuntu I have a directory called /home/lms. I've installed nodejs, angularjs and http-server but not gulp or bower as I won't be doing development in Ubuntu. I see in home/lms:

```
/Public
/Templates
/Pictures
/node_modules
```

How do I deploy my files? I assume I put my package.json in home/lms and but I can't copy Windows node_modules to Ubuntu node_modules so how do the node_modules get created for Ubuntu?

Also, do I put my application directory /src into the /home/lms/Public directory on Ubuntu or just add it to /home/lms?

Comment: Ah ok, so I can deploy directly from windows to Ubuntu and just use git as a backup I take it. Ok, I'll take a look at this on gulp deploy: http://mikeeverhart.net/2016/01/deploy-code-to-remote-servers-with-gulp-js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app was done wisely it should have deploy task in gulp that bundles everything. You shouldn't have to have node_modules on the server side but if you really want to do it you have to run npm install in the folder where package.json is.

Comment: Right. The package.json file is a recipe for building node_modules. You never need to move or back up that directory.